# javascript global variable in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to request a variable declared globally inside of the touchmove function but I'm getting a reference error. Does anybody know what's wrong?

```
function drawer(pulltab,drawer){
    $('#pulltab').on('touchstart',function(e){
        notworking=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    })

    $(drawer).on('touchmove',function(loc){
        var fingerloc=loc.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        var dist=fingerloc-notworking;
        console.log(dist);
        if (dist<0){
            $(this).css('margin-left',dist);
        }
    })

    $(drawer).on('touchend',function(){
        $(this).css('transition','margin-left .1s');
        $(this).css('margin-left',0);
    })
}
drawer('#pulltab','#navigation-drawer');
```

Comment: I don't see any global variable declarations in that code.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to request a variable declared globally inside of the touchmove function

There are no global variable declarations in your quoted code.

Assuming you haven't declared it, then you are *creating* (but not declaring) a global variable in the `touchstart` handler on `#pulltab`:

```
notworking=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
```

That uses [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* to create a global. But the global won't exist until that code runs.

Clearly, your `touchmove` handler on `drawer` is firing *before* your `touchstart` handler on `#pulltab`. Since there is no existing global called `notworking`, you can't read its value, and you get a `ReferenceError`. If the `touchstart` on `#pulltab` had executed first, you wouldn't.

Don't rely on the horror of implicit globals. Declare your variables. If you want it to be global, put

```
var notworking;
```

...outside all functions. (Although global variables are a Bad Thing™ best avoided; if you only use `notworking` within the `drawer` function and you don't need it shared between calls to `drawer`, just declare it within `drawer`.) You might also want to check, when using it, whether it has a useful value.

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*